# should i write jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json in .gitignore file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, gitignore

i have to use jsconfig file in my project, jsconfig file looks like that:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "src/*"
            ],
            "test/*": [
                "test/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

in nodejs or any front end project, should we ignore jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json in .gitignore file?
what is the best practice for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should leave your config file in your code repository, so when you or other person clone your project can run it with the same configurations that you're using right now